# Create dropdown list post

Tags: posts, menus, query-posts

I want to create a drop down list that will list all the posts in the category. I want the drop down list to appear on every post. So for example if I view a post that belongs to category Apples it should list all posts in category Apples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hey @Ruriko ... its a 3 step action.**

1. get the current category ID
2. get the posts for this specific category
3. get the posts into a select menu

Please note that this code would use the first
category id altough you might assign several
categories to the same post.
.

```
<?php 
    // FIRST CATEGORY NAME
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    $catID = $category[0]->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 5, 
        'category' => $catID            
    );
    $catPosts = get_posts( $args );

    echo '<form method="POST">';
    echo '<select name="goToPost" onchange="document.location=this.value">';
    echo '<option value="">'.__('Relevent Posts', 'your_text_domain').'</option>';  
    foreach( $catPosts as $singlePost ) {
    echo '<option value="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/index.php?p='.$singlePost->ID.'">'.$singlePost->post_title.'</option>';
    };
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers, Sagive.

Comment: It sort of works but when I select a post in the drop down list it doesn't go to that post. Is there a way to show all posts instead 5 only? since each category has different amounts of posts

Comment: aplogies... i left my testing code in there.. see my revised code - should work now (tested)

Answer (score 0):

To show all posts, using WP Query with `posts_per_page` value equals to -1.

Not exactly the answer but [here's an example](http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/create-dropdown-list-of-posts-from-a-category/) of using wp query

More on WP Query [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).